# Can't get order object in sales_order_place_after observer method in multi-shipping

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Hi guys i am working in magento 1.14 enterprise. i am trying to get order id after order place in multishipping checkout for that i am using this event

> sales_order_place_after

i also tried this one as well

> checkout_submit_all_after

but i am getting nothing in this event i want to get order id

here is my code for config

```
            <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>afterPlaceOrder</method>
                </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
```

and this code for function

```
 public function afterPlaceOrder($observer) {
    $helper = Mage::helper('marketplace');
    $lastOrderId = $observer->getOrder()->getId();

}
```

Its giving me error in this line **Call to a member function getId() to null** can anyone please tell me what i am missing why my observer is giving me nothing i have checked the same scenario in onepage and its working fine there.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

please try to get order by:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

so in result:

```
public function afterPlaceOrder($_observer) {
    $helper = Mage::helper('marketplace');
    $_event = $_observer->getEvent();
    $_order = $_event->getOrder();

    if (!$_order) {
        return $this;
    }

    $_lastOrderId = $_order->getId();
}
```